# How to read Windows Server 2008 in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, registry

i am trying o read registry value with the following code.

```
    Label1.Text = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Myweb\\ConnectionManager", "ID", null).ToString();
```

it work fine when i am trying in windows xp but i never works in windows server 2008.
any help Please

Comment: How was the key created on the Server? (It won/t be there automatically).

Comment: @Richard i have created the key.

Comment: @rene no i havn't tried from IIS. i believe its some thing to do with 64bit and 32 operating system.

Comment: @rene by going through regedit

Comment: @rene it works perfectly fine in windows xp but not in windows server 2008.

Comment: @rene i have tried ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Myweb\\ConnectionManager\\Wow6432Node", "ID", null).ToString();
but this doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running into the issue of the [WOW redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can use the more [specialized classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Microsoft.Win32 for getting either a 64 or 32 bits part of the hive.

```
 var root = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine
                                   ,RegistryView.Registry32); // or Registry64
 var flk = root.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");
 var slk = flk.OpenSubKey("Myweb");
 var tlk = slk.OpenSubKey("ConnectionManager");
 var val = tlk.GetValue("ID");

 Label1.Text = val.ToString();
```

Or a more general purpose method to get a registry value whatever it takes:

```
object GetValue64Or32(string path, string ValueKey)
{
     var parts = path.Split('\\');
     RegistryHive hive = RegistryHive.LocalMachine;
     switch(parts[0])
     {
        case "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE":
            hive = RegistryHive.LocalMachine;
        break;
        default:
           throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
     foreach(var view in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RegistryView)))
     {
        var key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, (RegistryView) view);
        for(var partIndex=1; partIndex<parts.Length;partIndex++)
        {
           key = key.OpenSubKey(parts[partIndex]);
           if (key == null) break;
        }
        if (key!=null) return key.GetValue(ValueKey);
     }
     return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var value = GetValue64Or32(
               "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Myweb\\ConnectionManager"
             , "ID");
Label1.Text = value!=null?value.ToString():"no value found";
```

If I use this registry file this code works for the 32 bits hive:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyWeb\]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyWeb\ConnectionManager\]
"ID"="id 1"
```

And this works for the 64 bits hive:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyWeb\]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyWeb\ConnectionManager\]
"ID"="id 1"
```

You can use `REG` from the commandprompt to verify if your registrypath exists:

```
reg query HKLM\Software\MyWeb\ConnectionManager /s
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. i tried you answer but its giving me object reference not set to an instance. on this line var val = tlk.GetValue("ID"); i tried both Registery32 and 64

Comment: excellent. Thanks alot job both are perfect answers. RegistryView.Registry64 it worked.